# Multicast playing of video inside SharePoint

Tags: web-part, content-editor-web-part, video

If I use the Flow Player (http://flowplayer.org/) to play videos (which is stored on a network storage) using the Content Editor Web Part in SharePoint 2007, will the videos operate in a multicast way and not uni-cast way? and also which will be responsible for the multicast operation - Flow Player or Content Editor Web Part or SharePoint Server or Network Storage or etc..?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take a look at IIS smooth streaming. You will never get any good streaming performance from SharePoint or a network drive.

Comment: Hi Wictor, are you refering to http://www.iis.net/download/smoothstreaming?

Comment: That's correct.